# Maven test fail on terminal but passes in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My Spring Boot application uses TestNG and it has the surefire plugin. I am attempting to package it on the terminal but it keeps failing on the maven test step. If I run the maven package command on IntelliJ, all the maven steps run fine and pass.

I am only getting errors like below when it is attempting to `mvn test` on the terminal/command line. What could it be? I thought it was a Mockito dependency issue but even after added it in my pom.xml nothing changed.

````
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class java.lang.Object, class org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger]
    at com.homedepot.appconfig.error.reporting.StackDriverErrorReporterTest.reportError_WithHttpRequest_False(StackDriverErrorReporterTest.java:112)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class java.lang.Object, class org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger]
    at com.homedepot.appconfig.error.reporting.StackDriverErrorReporterTest.reportError_WithHttpRequest_False(StackDriverErrorReporterTest.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at com.homedepot.appconfig.error.reporting.StackDriverErrorReporterTest.reportError_WithHttpRequest_False(StackDriverErrorReporterTest.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.homedepot.appconfig.error.reporting.StackDriverErrorReporterTest.reportError_WithHttpRequest_False(StackDriverErrorReporterTest.java:112)
Mockito cannot mock this class:```
````

Comment: Please follow this link and edit your querstion. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DavidLe were you able to solve this? I am running into exact same issue. I am using jdk 11, junit juniper 5.3.2, mockito-junit-jupiter 2.24.0 and mockito-core 2.24.4. My test passes when I run in IntelliJ and fails on terminal with the error you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the maven version and pom.xml file it is picking to run the test; this is my wild guess.

Comment: So using `mvn -version` I'm getting `Apache Maven 3.6.0` but looking at the pom.xml I see `3.8.0` for `maven-compiler-plugin` Could this be the mismatch issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `maven-surefire-plugin` was missing in the `<build>` section of the `pom.xml`. Add the plugin:

```
<build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>your-version</version>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>

<!--        other plugins ...-->

 </build>
```